# Speed Up a list

Tags: arrays, json, filter, model, swiftui

I'm try to speed up my APP that for now unfortunately is very slow on performing some search and list of data with Swift Ui.

first of all I have a data model that describe my object airport, called AirportModel

```
import Foundation

class AirportModel : Identifiable , Codable{
    var aptICAO : String
    var aptName : String
    var aptCity : String
    var aptCountry :String
    var aptIATA : String

init(aptICAO: String, aptName: String, aptCity: String, aptCountry: String, aptIATA: String) {
    self.aptICAO = aptICAO
    self.aptName = aptName
    self.aptCity = aptCity
    self.aptCountry = aptCountry
    self.aptIATA = aptIATA
}

}
```

I have a local file apt.json, that contain all the data information for my airport (I downloaded from internet this json, inside there are around 29000 airport)

so when I run the first time the app, with the following function , i create and save the airportVector of type AirportModel.

```
func openfilejson (fileName : String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let datafile = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl,options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let json = JSON(data:datafile)
                objectWillChange.send()
                for (key,_) in json {

                    let airport = AirportModel(aptICAO: "", aptName: "", aptCity: "", aptCountry: "", aptIATA: "")
                    airport.aptName = json[key]["name"].stringValue
                    airport.aptCity = json[key]["city"].stringValue
                    airport.aptCountry = json[key]["country"].stringValue
                    airport.aptIATA = json[key]["iata"].stringValue
                    airport.aptICAO = json[key].stringValue
                    airportVector.append(airport)

                }

                debugPrint("nel vettore airport Vector ci sono \(airportVector.count) aeroporti")
                save2() // to save airport vector in the plistfile
                debugPrint("SALVATO IN MEMORIA ")

            } catch {
                 print("ERRORE OPEN FILE AEROPORTI")
            }
        }
    }
```

all, this work fine , the vector with 29000 airport inside is created once the app is ru the first time.

NOW THE BIG ISSUE.

in one view, I try to list this airport using SwiftUI and a searchBar to search on it.

the problem is, due to the big amount of data to be opened, when I load the View with the list; the data take very long to be listed and moreover when I lunch the search everything is stuck!

any idea how can I process or speed up this huge amount of data to avoid the app stuck on the loading of the following view!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager
    @State private var searchTerm : String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("List")
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm).shadow(radius: 10)
            List(dm.airportVector.filter{
                 $0.aptCity.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
                    || $0.aptName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)
            }){ item in
                HStack {

                    Text(item.aptICAO).bold().font(Font.system(size:20)).frame(width: 90, height: 10)
                    //
                    Text(item.aptName).font(Font.system(size: 15))
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        Text(item.aptCity).font(Font.system(size: 10)).font(.subheadline)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(item.aptCountry).font(Font.system(size: 10))

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Damiano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your data conform to `Identifiable` and use `ForEach` inside of your `List` with a separate View to render the item:

```
List {
  ForEach(items) {
    MyItem(item)
  }
}
```

Only render items when they change by making `MyItem` conform to `Equatable`, and define the `==` function. Make sure the `==` function is being executed by adding a breakpoint or `print` statement. If it's not being executed see this article for a workaround:

https://swiftui-lab.com/equatableview/

---

If the above suggestion works, but you find yourself making wholesale modifications to the list after initial render, try using `id()` during these modifications. See https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/

---

If the above suggestions don't improve things enough, you probably need a more custom solution. Use a TableView or CollectionView, see https://github.com/apptekstudios/ASCollectionView

Comment: Definitely using a ForEach inside the list speed up quite a bit, now i'm try to speed up the search. Im try to use the id: \.self on the search Xcode say my model need to be conforme to hasable. Any tips how to create ,

Comment: I add Equatable and Hasable, but not sure how to use...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580088/swiftui-big-list-search

Comment: Step 1: accept + upvote this answer . Step 2: Open a new question with example code. But make your example code in the question the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Don't just dump your entire app's code in there because it makes it much more difficult for us to help you.